# Event like iOS touchUpOutside in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, ios, touch-event

Is there any kind of event that works like touchUpOutside is iOS?
touchDragInside? touchDragOutside?

Any kind of event that has began with a touchstart on an Element, but dragged outside of Element's frame?

Answer (score 2):

The W3C have defined a [`touchleave`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-touch-events-20110505/#the-touchleave-event) event, but in my experimentation, it's not yet been implemented in Mobile Safari. However, you can workaround this using a combination of the `touchstart` and `touchmove` events:

```
window.addEventListener('load', function() { // on page load

    var element;
    document.addEventListener('touchstart', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var touch = event.touches[0];
        element = document.elementFromPoint(touch.pageX,touch.pageY);
    }, false);

    document.addEventListener('touchmove', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var touch = event.touches[0];
        if (element !== document.elementFromPoint(touch.pageX,touch.pageY)) {
            var event = new CustomEvent("touchleave", { detail: { touches: event.touches, }, bubbles: false, cancelable: false });
            element.dispatchEvent(event);
        }
    }, false);

}, false);
```

You can the listen for the event on a particular element like this:

```
var box = document.getElementById('box');
box.addEventListener('touchleave', function(e) {
    // Handle the touch leave event here
}, false);
```

Comment: Thanks, this stands for touchDragOutside, if I'm right. Still have to figure out touchDragInside, and touchUpOutsite. Anyway, don't have touch events a .target that holds the touched element already?

Comment: Yes, it is `touchDragOutside`. For `touchUpOutside`, you'd dispatch an event from `touchend` when the element under the current touch point does not match the element from `touchstart`. There's sufficient detail in my answer for you to go ahead and implement this yourself. Including the element in the event object was just the remnant of some testing.

Comment: Yap. Probably I'll make some kind of view objects with a root controller watching the body.